# If I have set `disksleep` to 0 in pmset, will my disk go to sleep when I close the lid?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, pmset

I have `MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)` and `OS: 10.13.6`

My pmset outputs:

```
$ pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod, Google Chrome)
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         20
 acwake               0
 lidwake              0
```

You can see that I have set the `disksleep` to `0` somehow (not sure when I did that), will my disk go to sleep when I close the lid?

Comment: If this Mac (you don't specify which model) has an SSD, the `disksleep` command is meaningless as it applies to HDDs.

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks a lot for the reply. I have `MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)` and `OS: 10.13.6`.

Comment: This MBP came equipped with a 128, 256, 515 GB or 1 TB SSD, so `disksleep` has no effect.

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks a lot for the reply. so do you mean that ssd does not need to sleep? Even if I travel with a running ssd, there is no problem at all? Only the system needs to be in a sleep mode, ssd does not need to sleep? thanks.

Comment: I would assume the SSD is powered down while in sleep. An energized SSD does generate some heat, after all.

Comment: @IconDaemon ok, thanks a lot for the reply. if SSD does need to be powered down, maybe `disksleep` option does some effect on SSD too? Anyway, the whole `sleep` topic is kinda confusing and complex. The latest MacOS versions seem ignoring the values from pmset somehow. At least, `lidwake` does not work at all.

Comment: The disksleep command has _no effect_ on SSDs.

Comment: @IconDaemon if `disksleep` command has no effect on SSDs, but SSDs does need to be powered down, does it mean it's actually a bug in the latest MacOS release? Just similar to `lidwake` option has no effect on my MacOS `10.13.6` too, but it should work. If it's by design, where can I find the official design decision doc? Thanks.

Comment: No. You misunderstand. The disksleep command _only_ works on HHDs, which have mechanical mechanisms that draw power and generate heat. Most modern Macs use SSDs, so this command is somewhat of a legacy command, but still useful for the millions of spinning disks still in use. It’s presence is not a bug.

Comment: @IconDaemon ok, got it. thanks a lot for the clarification.